# Problema com Mongoose.find() usando regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Olá, pessoal. Eu estou com problema ao usar o Mongoose.find() com regex em um campo específico da model. Segue a imagem abaixo:

[image: Mongoose.find()]

"filter" é um parametro da função de um tipo DTO. Esse campo filter.subject precisa desse regex para permitir fazer a consulta de uma parte de um nome composto, por exemplo, Stack Overfllow -> passa só o Stack e o find retorna o document referente à esse nome.

O Problema é que esse filter não tem só o "subject" mas outros atributos e então, se for passado os outros atributos para fazer a consulta sem esse atributo "subject" o find não vai retornar nada, só está funcionado se eu passar o subject também na API. É possível criar um regex que aceita tanto esse regex atual quanto um que aceita deixar o campo subject como vazio, caso ele não for passado no endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

O problema não ficou tão claro, mas vou tentar te ajudar a partir do ponto que consegui entender.

1. Nesse exemplo que você fez de regex, não existe a necessidade de colocar `'.*'` para dar match.
2. Além disso, imagino que quando você diz *"fazer a consulta sem esse atributo "subject" o find não retorna nada"*. Pode ser que o valor de filter.subject acabe sendo `null` ou `undefined`, isso impacta no resultado do regex.

Para resolver isso, você pode fazer um tratamento antes de passar o filter.subject para o find.

Ou você também pode fazer o tratamento dentro do find da seguinte forma:

```
subject: { $regex: filter.subject || '' },
```

Além de tirar as partes com `'.*'` que são desnecessárias, adicionei o trecho `|| ''` para quando o filter.subject não for passado (sendo null ou undefined) ele vai utilizar uma string vazia (a string vazia vai dar match com tudo, então resolve o seu caso quando tiver outros filtros).

Acrescentando mais um detalhe, você pode utilizar regex options para complementar sua busca, mais detalhes [Aqui](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)